# Nginx reverse proxy instead of directory listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to have nginx serve static content while reverse proxying everything else to a rails server.

All that works, except for the home page. 
If I go to example.com I get a 403 error and the error log shows

```
2019/06/14 04:32:59 [error] 9746#9746: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden
```

I want the request to be sent to the rails server as example.com/ instead of trying (and failing) to get a directory listing. The rails server should display a homepage instead. (side note: if I turn autoindex on I will get a directory listing)

Configuration is here:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        server_name example.com;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            autoindex off;
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @rails;
            expires max;
            access_log off;
        }
        location @rails {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the `index` behaviour for all URIs, drop the `$uri/` term from the `try_files` statement. For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

Alternatively, add a new location block to specifically handle the URI `/`, for example:

```
location = / { 
    try_files nonexistant @rails; 
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 1):

A fix for the homepage would be to *add* an exact `location` for the homepage, like so:

```
    location = / {
        try_files @rails =404;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this works because rails would serve a page for anything. So it wouldn't check for static assets. (IOW: either you check rails first in which case rails serves everything or you check files first in which case you need to somehow exclude directory listings, which Richard Smith's answer does)

Comment: @xyious Richard's answer is definitely more correct, but take note that he includes adding exact matching for homepage similar to my answer. Note that I have exact matching that handes *only* `/`.

Comment: I misunderstood your solution. The "=" is very important, I glossed over that. Going to have to think about which one is better for what I'm trying to do, but yes, you're right.